# Needing help getting a unit test working

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, web, xml-serialization

I am having a devil of a time getting this to work...

Below follows a sample of a complex type our web services use.  The other overloads/parameters passed are primitives, DateTimes and the like.  I have some unit test methods that do a one-to-one comparison of the objects that I run when new code is checked-in and those pass just fine.  What I need to do now is implement (a class, perhaps?) something that captures the XML passed is the response so I can compare it to that being sent in the request.  Also, I need to build in the ability to change the data I am passing (to test negative cases/bad data), and I am completely stumped as to doing this.  Any and all help would be appreciated, and I will gladly provide more code upon request.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CrossReferenceCredentials", Namespace="http://www.pse.com/Namespaces/PSE.PSECom.InterfaceWebServices.Customer")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class CrossReferenceCredentials : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private string CustomerTokenField;

    private string SecurityIdField;

    private string UserNameField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string CustomerToken {
        get {
            return this.CustomerTokenField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CustomerTokenField, value) != true)) {
                this.CustomerTokenField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerToken");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string SecurityId {
        get {
            return this.SecurityIdField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.SecurityIdField, value) != true)) {
                this.SecurityIdField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SecurityId");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
    public string UserName {
        get {
            return this.UserNameField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.UserNameField, value) != true)) {
                this.UserNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What method are you trying to unit test? Do you want to test web service call? It a little bit nit clear for me.

Comment: You are correct, Petro.  I am attempting to test a service call.  What I want to do is capture the XML response, and to also be able to edit/change the XML request that the web service(s) are making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question, and actually ended up going a completely different route.  We purchased the full version of SoapUI and used that to do the bulk of our functional and unit testing.